# Cloning objects an arbitrary number of times

Tags: c++, sdl-2

I am a beginner C++ programmer using SDL2. Here is my question.

I am trying to clone an object of the same class an arbitrary number of times without having to specify a specific name to each of the new objects.

I define a class Enemy1:

```
class Enemy1
{
public:
//The dimensions of the enemy
static const int Enemy1_WIDTH = 20;
static const int Enemy1_HEIGHT = 20;

//Maximum axis velocity of the dot
static const int Enemy1_VEL = 10;

//Initializes the variables
Enemy1();

//Moves the enemy
virtual void move();

//Shows the enemy on the screen
virtual void render();

private:
//The X and Y offsets of the enemy
int mPosX, mPosY;

//The velocity of the enemy
int mVelX, mVelY;
};
```

I define all the functions within the class such as this:

```
Enemy1::Enemy1()
{
//Initialize the offsets
mPosX = 320;
mPosY = 240;

//Initialize the velocity
mVelX = 5;
mVelY = 5;
}
```

Then within my main loop:

```
        //Make first enemy
        Enemy1 enemy1;  

        //While application is running
        while (!quit)
        {
            //Handle events on queue
            while (SDL_PollEvent(&e) != 0)
            {
                //User requests quit
                if (e.type == SDL_QUIT)
                {
                    quit = true;
                }


            //Make more enemies
            if (SDL_GetTicks() > spawnTime)
            {
                    Enemy1 **arbitrary_name_of_copied_enemy**
                    spawnTime = spawnTime + spawnTimeInterval;
            }
        }
```

How do I go about doing this without having to name each new enemy? How is this problem typically handled? I've looked into copy constructors and cloning but they don't seem to solve this problem.

Comment: Search for arrays, or `std::vector`.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the copy constructor and presumably store them in a vector or array, then something like vector.push_back(new Enemy(orig)) will do the trick.